# Confusion about spontaneous symmetry breaking rod example

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I was reading a book on QFT and the example he uses to make an analogy of spontaneous symmetry breaking
in QFT is that of the rod where a compressive force is applied on the top surface of the rod directed down the
axis of the rod in line with the rod's axis.

[image: 1]

The rod bends and is no longer rotationally symmetric. I don't really understand
how it is "spontaneous". I did a little more digging and someone else who uses this example states that
SSB does not require an external force and as an example he showed if you apply another force tangent to
the top of the rod, this also breaks rotational symmetry **but isn't spontaneously broken**. But **both** of these examples use a force to break symmetry of
the rod. Why is
**one not spontaneous symmetry breaking** but the other **is spontaneous symmetry breaking**, since they are **both the same thing - applying
a force to break symmetry**?

Comment: Which book is it?

Comment: Cases analogous to tangential force are referred to as *explicit symmetry breaking*. In this rod example, the direction of the force explicitly selects out a preferred direction that the rod will bend.

Comment: @QuantumEyedea just for reference, Ryder (from the edit history)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I very much recall that example (many years ago!), and at the time it did confuse me too.

The most important thing to take from that example, is the fact that in the case of the force being applied in the longitudinal direction of the rod (from top pressing down) as in diagram (c) you have above, is that **the rod can bend in any direction**. That is, there are multiple different directions the rod could bend, meaning the final state of the rod, or the "ground state", is "degenerate".

This is not possible in the situation depicted in part (b) of the diagram, since even though rotational symmetry is broken, there is *only one direction* it will bend - in the direction of the force - and so this represents *explicit symmetry breaking* and there is only one possible "ground state".

Having degenerate ground states, or multiple vacuum states in QFT, is what defines the idea of [spontaneous
symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking) in QFT.

It is also worth noting two properties of this spontaneously broken state. First, as already discussed, is that the direction in which the
rod bends is arbitrary and therefore there are several "ground states" that could all be equally occupied: *the ground states are degenerate*.

The second thing to note
is that the different directions of bending (the different ground states) are related
by (the original) rotational symmetry. The symmetry has thus not "disappeared" but
is "hidden" in the relation between the ground states. This reflects the fact that
the equations of motion still obey the symmetry, although *the ground states do
not*, and sometimes spontaneous symmetry breaking is referred to as a *hidden
symmetry*.

Comment: Oh wow! It's so obvious! Thank so much Drjh. I finally get it.

Comment: No worries. You should have added pictures of the rod and before/after so that people without the book? you used can see what's happening. It is a good example.

Comment: I can probalby add it to the question if you think more people can learn form it.

Comment: I think it could help. Thanks.

Comment: I added a diagram so more can understand.